# Wildfly 9.0.2, fails to instantiate Spring bean

Tags: java, spring, maven, jboss, wildfly

We have an application currently running on Jboss 5.1 which needs to be migrated to Wildfly 9.0.2.

The structure of the deployment is in the form of an EAR, as follows:
app.EAR
--->someWeb.war
------>WEB-INF/lib
---------->third-party jars
---------->custom1.jar (Spring project)
---------->custom2.jar(Spring project)
--->resourceAdapter.rar

There is a dependency of a beanA defined in custom2.jar in a beanB defined in custom1.jar

The project uses a XML based Spring configuration, and each jar has a spring-bean xml config.

When the porject is deployed in Wildfly it fails to find beanA while instantiating beanB.

Been looking for an answer on Jboss and Wildfly forums, but couldn't find anything yet.
Any help in the right direction would be great.
Thanks

Comment: Are the Spring Framework jars also in WEB-INF/lib?

Comment: yes absolutely.

Comment: In theory all the classes in WEB-INF/classes and in the jars in WEB-INF/lib are in the same classloader, so that seems a bit odd. You're not using any annotation scanning then? Please show the complete stack trace.